# Irrlicht in Eclipse, environment not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, irrlicht

I am trying to use Eclipse C++ and Irrlicht to a project in school. My problem is to set op the environment.

I have used this http://irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.Macintosh

I am using the new MacBook Pro.

I think the error is in this flag.
[image]

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HalloWorld2 ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/helloworld.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/Users/JAMES/Code/irrlicht-1.7.2/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -arch i386 -fvisibility=hidden -MMD -MP -MF"src/helloworld.d" -MT"src/helloworld.d" -o "src/helloworld.o" "../src/helloworld.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/helloworld.cpp

Building target: HalloWorld2
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++ -L/Users/JAMES/Code/irrlicht-1.7.2/source/Irrlicht/MacOSX/build/Release -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/X11/lib -Xlinker -arch i386 -framework OpenGL -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -o "HalloWorld2"  ./src/helloworld.o   -lIrrlicht
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: i386: No such file or directory
make: *** [HalloWorld2] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of MacOS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the use of `-Xlinker` to pass arguments to the linker. The man page of `g++` says:

> -Xlinker option
>
> Pass option as an option to the linker.  You can use this to supply system-specific linker options which GCC does not know how to recognize.
>
> If you want to pass an option that takes an argument, you must use -Xlinker twice, once for the option and once for the argument.  For example, to pass -assert definitions, you must write -Xlinker -assert -Xlinker definitions.  It
>              does not work to write -Xlinker "-assert definitions", because this passes the entire string as a single argument, which is not what the linker expects.

Here `-Xlinker` appears only once whereas it should be appear between each argument sent to the linker. So a ugly solution is to write:

```
-arch -Xlinker i386 -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker OpenGL -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker Carbon -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker Cocoa -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker IOKit
```

---

But if you find a way to configure Eclipse to use `-Wl,` instead of `-Xlinker` it would be better I think:

> -Wl,option
>
> Pass option as an option to the linker.  If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.

Then you could use:

```
-arch,i386,-framework,OpenGL,-framework,Carbon,-framework,Cocoa,-framework,IOKit
```